# ReportViewer not displaying report properly in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, report-viewer2010

I am trying to run this report page which is being displayed on a page and it appears to work/display fine in IE but when i run it in Firefox or Chrome I only get the header bar of the report and either i have to refresh the report or page and then it will work - also tried clicking on the next and previous page arrows on the report header to display the report on the page properly. I am not sure what is the cause or if could be fixed but it something frustrating at times.

This is what i have for the page running/displaying the report:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ActivityReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="Kids.MVC.Reporting.ActivityReport" %>
```

```
<form id="form" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false" />
    <uc1:ReportViewer ID="reportViewer" runat="server" />
</form>
```

This is my ReportViewer display page I have:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportViewer.ascx.cs"
Inherits="Kids.MVC.Reporting.ReportViewer" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
<style type="text/css">
    .ReportViewer table
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
    .ReportViewer *  
    {
        background-image:none;       
    }
</style>
<div class="ReportViewer">
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" AsyncRendering="False"
        ExportContentDisposition="AlwaysAttachment" SizeToReportContent="true" BackColor="White" ShowRefreshButton="False">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
```

Comment: The web developer's mantra: "If it works in IE, but not the other browsers, you're code is wrong." Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work. But you aren't showing enough to help us help you. A link would be better but a jsfiddle would be fine if you show only the generated markup since most of us don't use asp.

Comment: @Rob - understood. But my code does work in Firefox and Chrome it is that i have to refresh to show the whole report and this might happen 2 out of 5 times. Sometimes it loads perfectly fine and others i have to refresh the page and i am not sure if there is a cause to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough i found the reason for the glitch. Since this was only happening to some reports i compared reports and noticed the reports which i had a line break caused the glitch and for the report not to show in FF or chrome (only showing the header of the report). So taking out the line break fixed my problem. I also replaced the line break with a bunch of under scores in a text box.

Answer (score 8):

There is a very simple fix for this. Put the ReportViewer control in a div, and set the div's height to a large number (1000px is a good, round choice).

Setting SizeToReportContent="true" can also fix this.

Either solution makes it work for me, but the OP already has it set to true, so it might not work in all cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Worked for me, too.  Such a simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

The deal is that Microsoft ReportViewer officialy does not support Chrome. 
This link should help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251673.aspx

 But it works perfectly in IE! :)

Say thanks to MS ;)

Comment: not sure whether to thank or not - it is very unsatisfying to offer clients a report page that works well on IE but for FF and Chrome i have to tell them to refresh - double click and give it a few seconds - cross your fingers and hope the report displays fully and not half of it. Thanks for the Info :D

Answer (score 1):

There is another fix for it, simply remove the `Doctype` from the page in which you have used the reportviewer.

If there is textbox rendering problem then set `CanGrow=false`

It is working for all the browsers in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ZoomMode="PageWidth"` and `SizeToReportContent="True"` attributes to `ReportViewer` control in **Viewer.aspx** page.

**Like:**

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" 
   runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" 
   ZoomMode="PageWidth" SizeToReportContent="True">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```